# 2022 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/4#questionnaire).**

---

Blender Stack Exchange is scheduled for an election [next week, 2022-11-07](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/4). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here’s how it’ll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2022-11-07 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The following two questions are guaranteed to be included:

  - How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
  - How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?
- The community team may also include the following three questions if the community doesn’t supply enough questions.

  - In your opinion, what do moderators do?
  - A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
  - In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. We exclude any suggested questions that are negatively scored.

  - We will post the final questionnaire on the [Election page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/election/4). Candidates will have the option to fill out the questionnaire, and their answers will appear beneath their intro statements.
  - This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 3):

A user is unhappy about a moderation decision. They post a complaint as a question in Blender's Stack Exchange accusing you personally of treating them unfairly. How do you react?

Answer (score 3):

What experience do you have, that would help you be a good moderator?

Answer (score 2):

How have you first come in contact with Blender and how long ago? Are you currently still actively using it professionally or for hobbies?

Comment: Copied from the last election: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2750/19307

Answer (score 2):

[Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=blender.stackexchange.com) is not a central part of this community, and engaging in conversations there is not required nor mandatory. It is however a good way to interact with more regular visitors and socialize a bit beyond the more cold and distant everyday Q&A, since Stack Exchange is often accused of being cold and impersonal.

Do you think reviving our chat rooms is a valid goal, or is it just a distraction from our main focus?

Do you think it will bring users closer together a encourage users to stick around more?

Do you have any ideas or suggestions to engage user in chat or encourage posting more often?

Answer (score 0):

How do you think the stack exchange sites should handle off-topic and opinion-based questions?

Comment: The Stack Exchange sites in general, or the Blender SE?

Comment: @Joachim Well, i think that even if we narrow the question to just Blender SE, it could be something that could be apply to any SE sites.